# What's the event of blockly structure change?

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I have a web app that include blockly and I want to be able to save the structure user created on blockly on backend db.
I just want to know how to get the current workspace structure so I can post it to server to save it.
and then load it again when user login.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Importing and exporting blocks](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/get-started/web#importing_and_exporting_blocks):

> If your application needs to save and store the user's blocks and restore them at a later visit, use this call for export to XML:
>
> `var xml = Blockly.Xml.workspaceToDom(workspace);
>   var xml_text = Blockly.Xml.domToText(xml);`
>
> This will produce a minimal (but ugly) string containing the XML for the user's blocks. If one wishes to obtain a more readable (but larger) string, use Blockly.Xml.domToPrettyText instead.
>
> Restoring from an XML string to blocks is just as simple:
>
> `var xml = Blockly.Xml.textToDom(xml_text);
>   Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(xml, workspace);`